# how to fix an error with amp&gt syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the following error. I'm creating a simple text based adventure, and I have no clue what's happening:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joelb\Desktop\bloodline\adventuremodules\game.py", line 2, in <module>
    from player import Player
  File "C:\Users\joelb\Desktop\bloodline\adventuremodules\player.py", line 52
    if i.damage &amp;gt; max_dmg:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

The error is occurring in my attack class ...

```
`def attack(self, enemy):
    best_weapon = None
    max_dmg = 0
    for n in self.inventory:
        if isinstance(n, items.Weapon):
            if n.damage &amp;gt; max_dmg:
                max_dmg = n.damage
                best_weapon = n`
```

Comment: It looks like somehow your text got converted to HTML, or perhaps you cut and pasted from HTML and got the HTML code instead of the simple python code. It may be useful to look at your editor or how you copied and pasted things to make sure it doesn't happen again. At any rate, operations like greater/less than should be < or = or > for any programming language. So while your final product will be complex, you should be confident you can look for simplicity in your individual lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it, replace

```
            if n.damage &amp;gt; max_dmg:
```

with

```
            if n.damage > max_dmg:
```

Most likely the original correct code contained `>`, which accidentally went through HTML entity encoding, thus `>` became `&gt;`, and that also accidentally went through HTML entity encoding, thus `&` became `&amp;`, the final output being `&amp;gt;`.